# designing a 10 threaded process

Tags: multithreading, shell, background, parallel-processing, subshell

I have some 500 odd data-files lying in a directory. I am processing these files using a command . Problem is it picks up each serially , of course  as would any utility 
For the moment what my process does is spawns some 500 processes , staggers them in batches of 10 each interspersed by a wait . Just like this . 1 file == 1 process per this design.

```
command1 <parameters> > log 2&>1&
command2 <parameters> > log 2&>1&
command3 <parameters> > log 2&>1&
command4 <parameters> > log 2&>1&  /# ....till 10
wait 
command11 <parameters> > log 2&>1&
command1 <parameters> > log 2&>1&
command1 <parameters> > log 2&>1& /# ...till 20 
wait
command1 <parameters> > log 2&>1&
```

So I dont pound the system away at the same time. The command is actually another series of shells and c code that parses the data files and does some checks, which involve connecting to Oracle. 
I'd like to re-design this so that every-time a command runs I don't open a new DB connection. So lets say there are 100 files . I want to open just 10 DB connections instead of 100 separate connections.
The way I want to do it is first count how many files I have. Divide them by 10. Each division is a 'batch' of 10 files-so instead of 100 there are  150  files, the process should automatically create 15 directories . Each directories should move in it 10 files and then 
I can run

```
 command1 <parameters> Directorypath  > log 2&>1& 
/# command can pick up all files in a directory or a single file
/# ct till command 10 ...
....
 command10 <parameters> Directorypath  > log 2&>1&
```

10 files== 1 process by this design.

Any suggestions visa a vis commands about how this can be done.
ty

Comment: Do you have any influence on what happens inside your `command`s? I mean, are you able to change the code of the `command`s? These `command`s are different programs, right? If not, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

with GNU parallel, you can run a command on all files in a directory in parallel, 10 at a time:

```
parallel --gnu -j 10 yourcommand --yourflags {} ::: *
```

and it would run

```
yourcommand --yourflags file1
yourcommand --yourflags file2
```

and so one, ten at a time.